# Bluetooth speaker ground wire connected to 4N25

Tags: arduino, ground, bluetooth, speakers

I am wondering if I can use a [4N25](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf) optocoupler to turn on/off two small speakers. The reason for doing this is that when I turn on the unit, I won't have to hear "device connected". Side note: it's connecting with Bluetooth to my Amazon Echo Dot.

I currently have an Arduino checking for voltage on the LED that's in it. It has red, blue, orange and green. The blue has the highest volts at 2.1vdc while the red has 1.3vdc. That's how I determine if it has gone to sleep or not:

```
red    = off/stand-by/sleep mode
blue   = bluetooth
orange = usb
green  = optical
```

Would I be able to hook both the right and left ground wires to one of these?

My thought is to turn the sound off during the time it reconnects to the Bluetooth (the "device connected") so that whenever it goes into sleep mode I can wake it up again without having to hear it, and then re-connect the ground wires back after a few seconds. This will happen after 10 minutes of sound not playing via the Amazon Echo Dot.

That's just how this Bluetooth speaker operates, which I dislike, but I don't want to purchase another one thinking that it too will have some sort of sleep mode, plus it's just more money to spend.

[image]

I am open to any other suggestion on how to do this some other way. This is just the only way I know how to combat this issue.

Comment: An optocoupler isn't what you would use for that.  You want a relay of some kind and you want it on the power wire to the speakers, not ground.

Comment: i was hoping this could be done without the use of a relay since i plan on putting the Arduino inside the Bluetooth speaker housing.

Comment: Could you provide the schematic you have? And are you sure that speakers aren't connected in a bridge configuration?

Comment: @StealthRT there are small relays like the IM02 series. Moreover, since it's most probably a Class D unipolar amplifier, you can just use a p-mosfet to block the PWM signal on the high side.

Comment: @sx107 Yeah im sure. It has 2 ground wires and 2 red wires. My schema is in my OP.

Comment: @sx107 How would that schema look for what you are talking about with the mosfet?